# Cookie Issue with External ELB AWS

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat, cookies, amazon-elb

We have in our system an Apache web server that proxies all petitions forward to an internal ELB and then to Tomcats running different apps. One of this apps sets up a cookie used to know whether the user has a session or not. This works very well using internal balancers. For some architecture issues, we have to change one of the balancers from an internal one to an external one. The problem is that when we want to access the apps that are running behind the external balancer from a php code running in the apache, the cookies don´t go through, and the external ELB changes all of them. The external ELB has its own subdomain.
The following is the code java where we set up the cookie :

```
public int validaLogin(HttpSession sesion,
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response, String usuario,
        int login_user_id) {
    final String sesion_username = (String) sesion
            .getAttribute(Utiles.CONST_USUARIO);
    int codigo = 0;
    if (sesion_username == null || usuario != null
            && !(usuario.equals(sesion_username))) {
        List<String[]> listaimei = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        listaimei.clear();

        sesion.setAttribute(URL, request.getQueryString());

        if (usuario != null) {
            sesion.setAttribute(Utiles.CONST_USUARIO, usuario);
            sesion.setAttribute("User", usuario);
            Enumeration<Locale> locales = request.getLocales();
            if (locales.hasMoreElements()) {
                Locale locale = (Locale) locales.nextElement();
                sesion.setAttribute("Locale", locale);
            }
        }

        if (login_user_id > 0) {
            sesion.setAttribute(Utiles.CONST_IDUSUARIO, login_user_id);
        }

        String login_ip;
        if (request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for") == null) {
            login_ip = request.getHeader("host");
        } else {
            login_ip = request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for");
        }
        sesion.setAttribute("ip", login_ip);
        SqlQuery.setUserInfoInSession(sesion, login_user_id);
        List<Integer> listaPermisos = SqlQuery.setUserPermisosInSession(sesion, login_user_id);

        // Obtiene lista de IMEI visible por el usuario
        objResultGetListaIMEI userIMEI = getlistaimeiFromDatabase(
                login_user_id, login_ip);
        codigo = userIMEI.getResultado();
        sesion.setAttribute(Utiles.CONST_LISTAIMEI, userIMEI.getListaImei());

        // Guarda sesion como Header
        response.setHeader("wpsid", sesion.getId());

        // Guarda sesion como Cookie
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("wpsid", sesion.getId());
        cookie.setMaxAge(-1);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        response.addCookie(cookie);

        // Agrega nueva sesion al hash 05/03/2014 CV
        WaypointSessionsInit.dsAddNewSession(sesion, userIMEI.getListaImei(), listaPermisos);

    }

    return codigo;
}
```